# Optimize array of component which have window event listeners

Tags: reactjs, optimization, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have array of data, which needed to render array of one and the same component which has window event listener. But if we have 20 event listeners on page then we have super freezing on page. How to have one event listener on array of one and the same component?

[image: Many event listeners]

```js
class BmResponsiveMenuButton extends PureComponent {
  lastWidth = 0
  resizeStep = 0
  state = {
    hidden: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  //HERE ADDING EVENT LISTENERS (TOTALLY WE HAVE 15-20 LISTENERS ON PAGE)
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, false)
    this.anchorMenuButton = document.getElementById(this.props.moreMenuButtonId)
  }

  handleResize = () => {
    this.handleHiddenOrNot()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.lastWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
  }

  handleHiddenOrNot = () => {
    this.resizeStep = Math.abs(this.lastWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth)

    let boundingMenu = this.anchorMenuButton.getBoundingClientRect()
    let boundingButton = this.anchorEl.getBoundingClientRect()
    if (boundingButton.right > boundingMenu.left - 10) {
      this.setState({
        hidden: true
      })
      this.props.onHide(this.props.id)
    } else {
      this.setState({
        hidden: false
      })
      this.props.onUnHide(this.props.id)
    }
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    this.handleResize()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, false)
  }

  handleExited = () => {
    let elem = this.anchorEl
    elem.style.opacity = '0'
    elem.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  }

  handleEnter = () => {
    let elem = this.anchorEl
    elem.style.opacity = '1'
    elem.style.visibility = 'visible'
    elem.style.position = 'sticky'
  }
  render() {
    const {
      title,
      url,
      classes,
      target,
      effects,
      effectType,
      index,
      active,
      currentModule,
      module
    } = this.props
    const transitionProps = {
      key: title,
      in: !this.state.hidden,
      enter: true,
      exit: true,
      timeout: !effects ?
        0 : {
          enter: this.resizeStep > 200 ? index * 100 : 300,
          exit: 200
        },
      onEnter: () => this.handleEnter(),
      onExited: () => this.handleExited()
    }
    let activeModule
    if (module && currentModule === module) {
      activeModule = true
    } else if (active) {
      activeModule = active
    } else {
      activeModule = url.includes(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash)
    }
    const ButtonComponent = ( <
      Link to = {
        url
      }
      target = {
        target
      }
      innerRef = {
        (node) => (this.anchorEl = node)
      } >
      <
      Button className = {
        classNames(classes.topNavigationButton, activeModule ? classes.selected : '')
      } > {
        title
      } <
      /Button> < /
      Link >
    )
    switch (effectType) {
      case 'slide':
        return ( <
          Slide direction = {
            'left'
          } { ...transitionProps
          } > {
            ButtonComponent
          } <
          /Slide>
        )

      case 'fade':
        return <BmFade { ...transitionProps
        } > {
          ButtonComponent
        } < /BmFade>

      case 'grow':
        return <BmGrow { ...transitionProps
        } > {
          ButtonComponent
        } < /BmGrow>

      default:
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Edited with code example. I use this component for displaying or hiding button if it not fit in window. I comment place where i create eventListeners

Comment: Show us some code too. It's hard to tell what the actual case is now.

Comment: @AKX ready. added

Comment: Looks like you could just do with a bit of debouncing. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function